# Virtualization with xHCI-IOV

Tags: usb, qemu, kvm, libvirt, pass-through

I need some documents about it (must be detailed) and,is KVM support it????

If yes, how to enable it and use it?

My goal is to virtualize intel usb controller(onboard 0000:00:14.0) and distribute it to 2 guests.

Passthrough can only be used by 1 guest.

Comment: Concerning the documentation, the specification is available [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/extensible-host-controler-interface-usb-xhci.pdf). Chapter 8 details the virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

xHCI-IOV is an xHCI-specific extension to SR-IOV (Single Root I/O Virtualization), the PCI specification that lets a single PCI device expose multiple *functions*.

Of the functions, one is a *physical function* and the others are virtual functions. Virtual functions have some limitations regarding the features they can support, but the spec says that no function cannot interfere with the functioning of the others.

However, I don't think Linux supports it.  The `XHCI_EXT_CAPS_VIRT` symbol only appears in debug code, and there should probably be a separate driver for virtual xHCI functions as well.